# OST Name used in Episode 25 Gundam Build Fighter Try

Tags: music, gundam-build-fighters-try

The Question is simple like the title said.
I've been searching the whole youtube and internet but won't get an easy hand
to it, so please help.

The music start in 20:30 - 20:57/To somewhere...
Here the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgRaknI3SZs

Comment: I believe it starts at 19:06

Comment: Right, i wasn't paying much attention, so do you know what's the name of that ost? i would be grateful...

Comment: Welp nmv, thanks for only care anyway. The OST is called "Power Resonance". Enjoy~

Comment: The problem seemed to be that I was searching In the OST for that series. I didn't know that Gundam re-used OSTs. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The song is "Power Resonance", [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_1j_uM5rN4)

According to [The OP,](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46686/ost-name-used-in-episode-25-gundam-build-fighter-try?noredirect=1#comment60872_46686)

> Welp nmv, thanks for only care anyway. The OST is called "Power Resonance". Enjoy~